# Python code not deleting record from database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

This is the code I have to delete a record from two tables in my database that share the same ID code and I'm not too sure where I've gone wrong. Anything missing? I've checked this a million times

```
def deletePhoto(photoID):

    """
    Middleware function to delete a photo post
    """

    #connect to the database
    conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

    #create sql to delete from the ratings table
    sql = """
    DELETE
    FROM ratings
    WHERE photoID= %s
    """

    #set the parameters
    parameters = (photoID)

    #execute the sql
    cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

    #create sql to delete from the photo table
    sql = """
    DELETE
    FROM photo
    WHERE photoID = %s
    """

    #set the parameters
    parameters = (photoID)

    #execute the sql
    cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

    #fetch the data
    data = cursor.rowcount

    #clean up
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: I think `parameters = (photoID)` should be replaced with `parameters = (photoID, )` (Note a trailing comma to make it a tuple)

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a sleeper after your executes.
It can take some time for the server to process your query.

```
import time
time.sleep(x)
```

x in seconds

Comment: The `conn.commit()` won't return until the server finished processing. A `time.sleep()` won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a *sequence* for the second argument. Using *just parentheses* does not create a sequence. To top this off, if `photoID` then that is a *sequence too*, one that consists of individual characters.

To create a tuple, you need to use a comma. Parentheses are optional here:

```
parameters = photoID,
```

or

```
parameters = (photoID,)
```

If you find it easier to avoid mistakes here, you could also make it a list:

```
parameters = [photoID]
```

You only have to do this once.

As a side note, you can use the MySQLdb connection object, as well as the cursor, as *context managers*:

```
with connection, cursor:
    ratings_delete = """
        DELETE FROM ratings
        WHERE photoID= %s
    """

    cursor.execute(ratings_delete, (photoID,))

    photo_delete = """
        DELETE FROM photo
        WHERE photoID = %s
    """

    cursor.execute(photo_delete, (photoID,))
```

The `with` statement will then take care of closing the cursor and connection for you, and if nothing has gone wrong in the block (no exceptions were raised), will also commit the transaction for you.